# KVL/KCL and Thevenin Concept

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, kirchhoffs-laws, thevenin, network

I have solved the following question but little bit confused that this solution is correct or not as attached in figure.

How can I solve this question by KCL/KVL also if by using Thevinin theorem its answer is incorrect?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - is this asking about adding a 5 ohm resistor between the two terminals on the right?

Comment: But where is the load?

Comment: @G36 Given the result I see for the load current it must be attached at the far right onto the loose leads over there.

Comment: @BeB00 yes resistor will be connected to right place...It is considered as load and currently no load

Comment: Lazy rounded in between, but OK

Comment: Showing us your attempt at a KVL/KCL solution may result in re-opening.

Answer (score 1):

I interpreted the request like this:
[image]

Comment: +1 for effort.  But your result is incorrect. It looks like you haven't assigned a value to R6. And this is why your answer is wrong.  The OP answer is good.